# How to convert byte[] to IMediaSample on C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Following some samples i saw on this site im trying the following code:

```cs
var byteArray = new byte[m.Length -10];
myMemoryStream.Position = 10;
myMemoryStream.Read(byteArray,0,(int)myMemoryStream.Length-10);

GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(byteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();

IMediaSample pSample  = null;

Marshal.PtrToStructure( pointer,pSample);

pinnedArray.Free();
```

But i recieve a "NullArgumentException" when calling Marshal.PtrToStructure( pointer,pSample).

Of course i know the reason of that error, what i would like to know is the right way to do it.

If you need more information tell me and i will add it as fast as i can.

Please help.

Comment: Yes, that's inevitable when you pass null for the second argument for PtrToStructure().  It needs to be a Type or a non-null object so that Marshal class can call object.GetType().  The snippet provides no help to guess how you intend to use the IMediaSample interface.  You either implement it yourself or you use the stock CMediaSample implementation.  There's no scenario where you can create an instance of it from a blob of bytes.

Comment: Could you provide an example of using CMediaSample please ? cause i dont know what you mean, i just started with this language about a week ago so mi ignorance is wide in every way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the actual structure, which also implements the `IMediaSample` interface.

```
public struct IMediaSampleStructure : IMediaSample
{
    // Implementation.
}
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
IMediaSample pSample = new IMediaSampleStructure();
Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, (IMediaSampleStructure)pSample);
```